# How to add another partition on a new laptop?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

Ok, wait, this question it's not a duplicate, please read until the end. :)

Usually I install Windows by myself and I get only one partition.

I got a new win8 laptop and there is the system partition + 2 recovery partitions:

[image: partitions]

So, I have two questions:

1. Can I add a new partition? Because the limit for MBR is 4 primary partitions. Or nowadays disks are using GUID by default? <strike>How I can check?</strike> (Right click on the drive in drive management and select properties)
2. If I add a new partition by shrinking C, the recovery will still work? (as it will become the 5th partition, not the 4th)

Comment: Ok, since the laptop uses EFI to boot Windows, the disk is partitioned with GUID, so I can create up to 128 partitions

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to shrink C by 200 gb and add a new partition

Comment: I think you'll want to create simple volume.

Comment: Yes but I want to be sure that in this way the recovery won't be damaged. If it is MBR, the recovery will access the wrong partition. With GUID, **MAYBE** it doesn't matter, because it has a unique identifier.